# Horizontal menu style "spill" over submenu

Tags: javascript, css, html, menu, styles

I have a horizontal menu with another horizontal submenu.  The problem I have is with styling.  I am trying to make it so that when a mainmenu element is activated and the corresponding submenu is shown then the mainmenu elements coloring kind of bleeds to cover the white-space between the two menus as in the following image:

[image: "Bleeding menu"]

Just to clarify the picture above is a rough image manipulated approximation on what I am searching for.

I am doing this in CMS Made Simple so this is only an approximation of the code:

```
 <nav id="mainmenu">
       <ul>
           <li>Main Menu 1</li>
      </ul>
 </nav>

<nav id="submenu">
      <ul>
           <li>Submenu 1</li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that shows the problem; there's no way to diagnose the issue without it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided no code I have created with a vague idea : 
http://jsfiddle.net/FLnke/

```
<nav id="mainmenu">
   <ul>
       <li onmouseover="javascript:opensub()" onmouseout="javascript:closesub()" >Main Menu 1 |
           <div id="submenu"></br>
  <ul>
       <li>Submenu 1</li>
       <li>Submenu 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
       </li>
       <li>Main Menu 2</li>
  </ul>
```